# Set environment path inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In windows, I have set an environment path to `“D:\FFMPEG\bin”` so that it is accessible in cmd. How can I do the same inside a docker container?

**Attempt 1** - Inside docker file, I did - `ENV PATH="D:\FFMPEG\bin:${PATH}"`. Also did

```
ENV PATH=".\FFMPEG\bin:${PATH}"
```

**Attempt 2** - In my docker-compose.yml, I did -

```
env_file:
      - ./.env
```

my .env has - `FFMPEG_PATH=./FFmpeg/bin`

How can I set an environment path inside the container, like in windows?
Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.5

ENV APP_HOME /app

WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY . /app

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential gcc libsndfile1

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install python-dotenv

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["app.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  web:

    build: .

    ports:

      - "5000:5000"

    volumes:

      - ".:/app"

    env_file:

      - ./.env
```

Folder structure

```
Heroku
  app.py
  Dockerfile
  docker-compose.yml
  FFMPEG
      bin
         ffmpeg.exe
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

Comment: Thank you but not quite what I am looking for. I can copy the files. How do I set an environment path?

Comment: Is it a Linux container?  You need forward slashes and no drive letters.  What is the environment variable getting set to, and how are you verifying it's right or wrong?

Comment: So I am new to docker. Might need a little help. For your first q, I am pulling from python3.8.5, and I am unsure of the  type of container. Cold you elaborate in an answer about forward slashes and no drive letters? Something like `.\FFMPEG\bin`. Also, I am not sure how to verify. Right now I just build it to test if mya application runs after making changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You best bet is to install `ffmpeg` in your container using `apt`. You cannot use a Windows binary in a Linux container.

```
RUN apt update && apt install -y ffmpeg # ...
```

By default, `ffmpeg` will be on PATH.

But to answer your original question: if you must update PATH for some other reason you can do:

```py
ENV PATH=$PATH:/app/bin
```

But it doesn't sound like this is necessary in this case.

Keep in mind that the filesystem inside your docker image is completely separate from your host filesystem. If your container will need files or binaries, they must be copied into the container using `COPY` or created directly as part of the build process (e.g. using `RUN`) or mounted in using `-v` argument to `docker run` at runtime.

If your host system is Windows and the container image uses Linux, binaries that work on Windows (`.exe` files) will not be compatible inside your container.